# How to display the current day + 30 days with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I try to insert the date of today + 30 days. First of all I tried to display the current date with the following code:

```
<script>
var date = moment.unix(1414543560).locale('de').format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
document.write(date);
</script>
```

This displays the right day and Month, but unfortunately the Year is wrong (it's actually 2014)

How can I display the correct date of today + 30 days? Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/e3a7bgLu/3/

Comment: Where are you getting this number from: `1414543560`?  If you want today+30, you need to start with -- um -- today?  Look at the `Date` object, it has day manipulation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Also you are tagging your question wtih jQuery yet you are using no jQuery code, but the moment library.

Comment: Start by reading the moment.js docs

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var date = moment().add(30, 'days').locale('de').format("DD. MMMM YYYY");
document.write(date);
```

This takes the current date (`moment()`), adds 30 days (`add(30, 'days')`) and formats the date.

This should all be very obvious after you read the moment.js documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDate(date,days){ 
      var d=new Date(date); 
      d.setDate(d.getDate()+days); 
      var month=d.getMonth()+1; 
      var day = d.getDate(); 
      if(month<10){ 
           month = "0"+month; 
      } 
      if(day<10){ 
           day = "0"+day; 
      } 
      var val = d.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+day; 
      return val; 
}

console.log(addDate("2014-10-10",30));
#output
2014-11-09
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question. OP is using MomentJS and is asking how to add 30 days to the date he wants to format. OP is not asking for a date formatting function.

Comment: Sorry? I don't quite understand.

Comment: i just give him a native javascript method

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a UNIX timestamp to the `Date` contructor in JavaScript set the date to 30 days in the future and pass that date to Moment.

```
// Construct date from UNIX timestamp
var date = new Date(1414543560 * 1000)

// Set date to 30 days in the future
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30)

// Format date using Moment
var formatted = moment(date).locale('de').format('DD. MMMM YYYY')
```

Note that if your support target allows it you don't even need Moment anymore, you can use the built-in [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) that comes with the browser.

```js
// Construct date from UNIX timestamp
var date = new Date(1414543560 * 1000)

// Set date to 30 days in the future
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30)

// Format date using Intl API
var formatted = date.toLocaleDateString(['de-DE'], {
  day: '2-digit',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
})

document.write(formatted)
```